# multiple where condition for checking NULL value in symfony1.4 and doctrine

Tags: doctrine, symfony-1.4, dql

I am using symfony1.4 and doctrine. I need to check a condition where the value is `NULL`. I nedd to write a query where `status = 1` and `start=NULL` and `end= NULL` and `estimated_time != NULL` .I have tried with this but i am not able to get the result.

```
            $tickets = Doctrine_Core::getTable('table')
              ->createQuery('a')
              ->where('status=?','1')
              ->andWhere('start=?', '')
                              ->andWhere('end=?', '')
              ->andWhere('estimated_time!=?','')
              ->orderBy('id DESC');
```

any help will be greatly appreciated.Thank You..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `IS NOT NULL`:

```
$tickets = Doctrine_Core::getTable('table')
    ->createQuery('a')
    ->where('status=?','1')
    ->andWhere('start IS NOT NULL')
    ->andWhere('end IS NOT NULL')
    ->andWhere('estimated_time IS NOT NULL')
    ->orderBy('id DESC');
```